# How do you determine if a website was created using the Ruby language?

Tags: websites

Without being able to look at the backend of a web app and only viewing the source code:  Are there any certain directory structures that are common to Ruby? I'm looking to learn the language, but I am for searching for websites that I would want to emulate as a learning modality.

Comment: could you elaborate (by editing your question) on how this relates to reverse engineering, please? There's already one close vote on your question ("unclear what you're asking"), although not from me.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/33140

Comment: If you can see the source code of the web app, it should not be difficult to determine whether it's written in Ruby...

Comment: The reason why it has to do with reverse engineering is that there is a web application that I would like to emulate and I'm not sure if it's built with Ruby or PHP. I know if I look at the source code and can see whether it's WordPress or the other basic CMS is but  what is the process of figuring out and determining whether it is in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Googling brought me this:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-directory-structure.htm

```
demo/
..../app
......../controller
......../helpers
......../models
......../views
............../layouts
..../components
..../config
..../db
..../doc
..../lib
..../log
..../public
..../script
..../test
..../tmp
..../vendor
README
Rakefile
```